# XNA and Draw rotation

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, rotation

From Wikipedia the ([image](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aDegree-Radian_Conversion_it.svg)) conversion degrees / radians shows the quadrants so that the increase of radians causes a counter-clockwise rotation but when using the following code the sprite is rotated clockwise:

```
rotation = (rotation + 0.5f) % MathHelper.ToRadians(360);
...
spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, sprite_center_other_sprite, new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50), Color.White, rotation, new Vector2(width/2, height/2),1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
```

Why? The direction is a convention or XNA is different?

Comment: Are you sure about the first line? MathHelper.ToRadians(360) is exactl 2Pi, which is available as a constant from MathHelper. Also, why do you add 0.5 radians to the rotation? Did you mean half Pi?

Comment: @Marton, Yes I'm sure that line does a rotation between 0 and 6,14 radians at 0.5 step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527531/xna-question-about-rotation) on SO:

> The XNA SpriteBatch works in **Client Space**. Where "up" is Y-, not
>   Y+ (as in Cartesian space, projection space, and what most people
>   usually select for their world space). This makes the rotation appear
>   as clockwise (not counter-clockwise as it would in Cartesian space).

So, that said, if this code is intended to prevent the angle from getting too large, consider using the `MathHelper.WrapAngle()` method. This method wraps the angle you give it (in radians) to between π (180°) and -π(-180°).

```
rotation = MathHelper.WrapAngle(rotation + 0.5f);
```

Note: If it is in your `Update` statement, you may also want to multiply the 0.5f against the elapsed game time so that your rotation speed is per second and not per `Update`. The final line would be:

```
rotation = MathHelper.WrapAngle(rotation + 0.5f * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds);
```